# jquery post ajax call session doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm really lost here while trying to send a session with my jquery ajax post call, here is a simplified example of my code.

File fom which request is sent:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $token = md5(rand(1000,9999));
    $_SESSION['contactToken'] = $token; 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.post(ContactUrl,{req:"contact_sub",tok:"<?php echo $token; ?>"},function(contactAns){
        alert(contactAns); return false;
    });
</script>
```

File request is sent to:

```
<?php
if(@isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="url"){
    if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) ){

        session_start();
        $token = $_POST['tok'];
        $sess_token = $_SESSION['contactToken'];

        if($token == $sess_token){
            echo "sessions match"; exit();
        }
        else{
            echo "sessions does not match"; exit();
        }
    }
    else{echo "error"; exit();}
}
else{echo "error"; exit();}
?>
```

At first the session was not getting recognized, I made all the checks - made sure it was setup in the first place made sure it was posted, declared session start on both pages, never the less if i tried to do this on the second file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$token = $_POST['tok'];
$sess_token = $_SESSION['contactToken'];

print_r($_SESSION['contactToken']); exit();
?>
```

I would get an empty alert. Then I transferred the session start to the top of my script on the second page and started getting a value for the session:

```
<?php
session_start();
$sess_token = $_SESSION['contactToken'];

if(@isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="url"){
    if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) ){

        $token = $_POST['tok'];
        echo "$token, $sess_token"; exit();

    }
    else{echo "error"; exit();}
}
else{echo "error"; exit();}
?>
```

And what I'm getting now is that the posted variable changes each time I refresh the page but the $sess_token always gives me the same value: 0589dd536fd043ff3865f8223fef3030

I really dont understand this wierd behavior, can some one please assist me with this?

Comment: are you mixing PHP and jQuery in your first code? o.0 session_start(); $.post(ContactUrl,{req:"contact_sub",to~~

Comment: no ofcourse not I just gave the an example of the code without wrapping it

Comment: @AlbertKuzmin Please wrap PHP code between `<?` and `?>`.

Comment: What's the value of your `$token` js var? If its a JS var.. I believe you meant `<?php echo $token; ?>`

Comment: Its a random hash which cahnges each time the page is refreshed

Comment: Yeah, that's your issue.. `$token` is a PHP var, not a JS one. Just added an answer for you..

Comment: my bad in postion the code in my real code im echoing the js from php thats why its was written like this ive updeted it

Comment: What's the output in your `File request is sent to:`? "Sessions match", "Sessions does not match" (check your grammar), first "error", or second "error"? What's the value for `$_POST["tok"]`? What about `$_SESSION["contactToken"]`?

Comment: The PHP file where you have your `$.post()` script is different of the PHP file where you process the submitted data? You should give files some name to keep track of them easily..

Comment: Like I expalined in the questions the sessions do not match becouse the $_POST['tok'] chages like its supposed to while the $_SESSION['contactToken'] fetched always has the same value as if its not being updated

Comment: @AlbertKuzmin I wrote a quick test script and I get matching tokens.  It's clear you don't understand fully what you're trying to accomplish, I even answered based on your question and you dv'd it - I shouldn't have even answered such a poorly formed question in the first place, so I deserve the dv.  [How to Ask Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Good luck

Comment: Too bad this question went so far off topic and I didnt get a solution to my problem. I did make mistake in my initial post which confused the user Joaquin to give me a wrong answer. As for your answer - lets assume my question was SO badly formed that you didnt understand it - looking at the code alone you could have figured out that Im generating a RANDOM varialbe for security purpuses so using some logic you could have figured out I need that session to be random and my problem was with the session not getting updated, that is why I gave you a down vote which you actually did deserve.

Comment: @AlbertKuzmin Oh, you gave up pretty quick.. I tested your code a little bit *refactored* and updated my answer.. Check it out and let me know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're using a PHP var in an JS script without wraping and echoing it.. Here is your code modified:

You're also trying to contatenate with `.` in JS. That's from PHP too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.post(ContactUrl, {
        req: "contact_sub",
        tok: "<?php echo $token; ?>"
    }, function(contactAns) {
        alert(contactAns); 
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

---

## Update

I came back to this answer again today. This is what I did:

**FILE**: `index.php`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $token = md5(rand(1000,9999));
    $_SESSION["contactToken"] = $token; 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.post("myOtherScript.php", {
      req:"contact_sub",
      tok:"<?php echo $token; ?>"
    }, function(contactAns){
      alert(contactAns);
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

**FILE**: `myOtherScript.php`

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $sess_token = $_SESSION["contactToken"];

   if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] == "XMLHttpRequest")){

      $token = $_POST["tok"];
      echo $token ." - ". $sess_token;

   } else {
      echo "Not an AJAX request";
   }
?>
```

What I get is the alert where one token is equal to the other and both are refreshed each time I reload the `index.php` file.

As a conclusion, your problem **is not in the code you shared.**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion im actually echoing the js script from the php that why its written like that I updated my code in the question - my problem is with the sessins

Comment: @AlbertKuzmin By taking and copying his answer and replacing your example with it, it affects the entire context of the question and its answers.  -1

Comment: Im not replacing my code with the answer - like I said beofre I made a mistake in posting the code since in my real code im echoing the js script from server side like so: $script='<script></script>'; thats why i enclosed the php varialbe in '..' instead of <?php ?>. this was not my problem in the first place the variable was set up just fine.

Comment: Thank you my friend you are absolutly right, after making more checks I found out that I had another session_start() declared on an included page that was intefering with this one, I fixed the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Had the same problem and it was about where session_start() is, before, after or in the include() of the same script.